# Lost ASP Session Variable IIS 6.0 to 7.5

Tags: asp-classic, iis-7.5, iis-6, session-variables, session-cookies

I've read a lot about the topic, but I don't get the solution. 
I've tried all the solutions the community has posted, but not success.

I am migrating a site from IIS 6.0 to 7.5. The site has both ASP and ASP.NET applications, so I set two different pools. 
The ASP.NET apps work without problems.

Where I have the problems is with the ASP applications. All the ASP apps use another app whose objective is to grant the user. The problem becomes when the granting-user app creates a `session ("accepted")` variable and it gets lost when redirecting. **This feature was working in IIS 6.0**

I've traced the problem and confirmed that the error comes when redirecting.

What I've tried and checked to fix the problem:

1. Session Properties

   - Enable Session State = true
   - Time-out: 00:20:00
   - Mode Settings: In Process
   - Cookie Settings = Use Cookies
   - Use hosting identity form impersonation = checked
2. Port to access the site: :8685
3. I've also checked the web-gardening and it's not enabled as there's only 1 working process set.

*I attach the screen captures I consider relevant*

[image: ASP Settings][image: Session State Settings][image: ASP Pool Settings]

---

I've coded an ASP page which shows the session variable contents. Before redirecting, the session variable is correctly created, but when the redirection takes place, the information is lost.

I attach the code my enterprise policy let me to post:

```
response.write("Accepted: " & session("aceptado") & "<br>")
response.write ("SQL: " & mySQL & "<br>")
response.write("Accepted: " & session("aceptado") & "<br>")
dim i,j
j = Session.Contents.Count
Response.Write("Session contents: " & j & "<br>")
Response.Write("Contents: <br>" )
For Each i in Session.Contents
    Response.Write(i & "<br>")
Next

Response.write("isNull: " & IsNull(Session) & "<br>")
Response.write("¿Aceptado? " & Session("aceptado"))
```

With the above code, the result is:

[image: Session correctly created]

The code to check the session status once the redirect takes place is:

```
<%response.buffer = true 
%>
<html>
    <h1>test</h1>
    <%
        dim i,j
        j = Session.Contents.Count
        Response.Write("Session contents: " & j & "<br>")
        Response.Write("Contents: <br>" )
        For Each i in Session.Contents
            Response.Write(i & "<br>")
        Next
    %>
    isNull: <%=IsNull(Session)%> <br>
    ¿Aceptado?: <%=Session("aceptado")%><br>
    incidencia : <%=Session("tipoincidencia")%><br>
    usuario : <%=Session("usuario")%>
</html>
```

The result executing the above code:

[image: Test page]

***The redirection takes place between the last two images***

Comment: The `Session State` properties has absolutely no bearing on Classic ASP session state it is ASP.Net specific *(which is why in IIS 7 and above it is under the ASP.Net section)*. Looks like in the ASP Session properties `New ID on Secure Connection` is set to `True`, does the redirect switch protocol HTTP to HTTPS perhaps? See [Classic ASP session weirdness between HTTP and HTTPS](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23266202/692942).

Comment: No HTTP to HTTPS switch protocol takes place. I've tried to change the 'New ID on Secure Connection' to False but there's no difference

Comment: Appreciate all of the screenshots you have provided but without any code *(specifically where the redirect is called)* can't help any further.

Comment: I've just updated the question. Due to my enterprise policy, I'm not able to post all the code. 
The redirect is after `Response.write("¿Aceptado? " & Session("aceptado"))` line becomes executed. The redirect goes to the second image (**the one with the test header**)

Comment: Thanks for providing the code, it's helpful but the `Response.Redirect` is what we are interested in, that just shows before and after.

Comment: It's just a line at the end of the asp page: `Response.Redirect("./verificar.asp")`. When this line becomes executed, you get the **test** header page (last image of the question). 
If you don't execute (comment) the `Response.Redirect("./verificar.asp")`, you get the web shown on the 4th image of the question (Accepted: True SQL: ...)

Comment: In which case I can only think of a few things that could cause it, `1.` There is a manual `Session.Abandon()` in the code. `2.` The config for the page has `Enable Session State` set to `False`. `3.` `verificar.asp` is running in a different Application Pool to the rest of the pages.

Comment: I've all checked and it's all correctly configured... Don't know what's happening.... Thanks Lankymart

Comment: It sounds really strange, what about creating another page to capture the `Session` and doing a test `Response.Redirect` to that is the behaviour the same?, would rule out the page being the problem.

Comment: That is what I made and the results are the last two images. The page 1 is where the variable session is created/filled and the second one is where we capture the session variable and print its content. The way we reach the second one from the first one is with the `response.redirect`.
I've found that with the `server.tranfer`, it works...

Comment: Sounds like it might be this issue - http://stackoverflow.com/a/5205700/692942 Appears to be related to using a custom port.

Comment: I also tried this... Not working for me... I'm going to try to run the applications under another IIS 7.5 Server...

Comment: Also ASP.Net sessions have some weird behaviour and that might be causing a conflict with the Classic ASP, disable it if you don't need it. In relation to ASP.Net session - [Don't redirect after setting a Session variable (or do it right)](http://weblogs.asp.net/bleroy/Don_2700_t-redirect-after-setting-a-Session-variable-_2800_or-do-it-right_2900_)

Comment: Also maybe of interest - [Losing session variables when switching pages classic ASP RSS](http://forums.iis.net/t/1213137.aspx?Losing+session+variables+when+switching+pages+classic+ASP)

Comment: The only other thing I can think of is something may be stripping the cookie out, like a proxy server / firewall?

Answer (score 0):

My Workaround for this is to simply start a ajax call every X (where X is roughly half the time in wich the session expires, in my case 7.5min ).

It's not super clean, but gets the job done.